# In R, how can I do this calculation (1 - sigma(the squre of certain value) using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am newbie in R.

Below is the sample of what I want.
I want to calculate the index, which is referring to ( 1 - the squre of prop's sigma by each "Country"
For example, in the case of Afghanistan, 1 - (0.006^2 + 0.009^2 + 0.32^2 + 0.008^2 + 0.006^2 + 0.524^2 + 0.19^2 + 0.88^2 + 0.19) = 0.6141.How can I make a code in R?

```
   Source  Date Country     Language          Number  prop index
 1 eb      2001 Afghanistan Pashai            160000 0.006   0.6141
 2 eb      2001 Afghanistan Balochi           240000 0.009
 3 eb      2001 Afghanistan Dari (Persian)    8290000 0.32 
 4 eb      2001 Afghanistan "Nuristani group"  200000 0.008
 5 eb      2001 Afghanistan Pamir group        160000 0.006
 6 eb      2001 Afghanistan Pashto            13560000 0.524
 7 eb      2001 Afghanistan  Turkmen            500000 0.019
 8 eb      2001 Afghanistan  Uzbek             2280000 0.088
 9 eb      2001 Afghanistan  Other              490000 0.019
10 eb      2001 Albania     "Albanian "         2419000 0.38  Index(what I want above)
11 eb      2001 Albania     "Albanian "         5369000 0.65
12 eb      2001 Albania     "Albanian "         2259000 0.46
13 eb      2001 Albania     "Albanian "         3392000 0.78
14 eb      2001 Albania     "Albanian "         3468000 0.26
15 eb      2001 Korea       "Korean "           7891900 0.38 Index(what I want above)
16 eb      2001 Korea       "Korean "           3485200 0.65
17 eb      2001 Korea       "Korean "           1413400 0.46
18 eb      2001 Korea       "Korean "           6419000 0.78
19 eb      2001 Korea       "Korean "           2419000 0.26
```

Comment: Could you please add the result of `dput(head(df,19))` to your post (replace df by the name of your dataframe) ? In this format your data is not easy to use in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that take a vector of values and calculated your index and then group the dataframe by the Country column and summarise to get the index by country. If you want to keep the whole data.frame with a index value for all rows then use `mutate` instead of `summarise`.

Not you don't strictly need to name the function first to use it, its just a bit neater.

```
library(dplyr)

calcindex <- function(prop){
  ind <- 1-sum(unlist(lapply(prop, function(x) x^2)))
  return(ind)
}

df %>% group_by(Country) %>% 
  summarise(index = calcindex(prop))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# Country      index
# <fct>        <dbl>
#   1 Afghanistan  0.614
# 2 Albania     -0.455
# 3 Korea       -0.455
```

If you are interested in using `purrr` as well as `dplyr` a more readable form of `calcindex` is

```
calcindex <- function(prop){
    ind <- 1-sum(map_dbl(prop, ~.x^2))
   return(ind)   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in first time you create a new table

```
table2<-table(your_table$Country)
df_table2=data.frame(table2)
```

and you get a table like this :

```
table2:
1Afghanistain 9
2Albania      5
3Korea        5
4Algeria      6
```

and we start with the first country this way :

```
n1=table2[1,2]
s=0
for(i in n1){
s=s+your_table$$prop[i]^2
}
your_table$$index[1]=1-s
```

with the rest you do this

```
n=nrow(your_table)
c=2
s=0

for(i in 10:n){
if (your_table$$Country[i]!=your_table$$Country[i-1]){
n1=table2[c,2]
for(j in 1:n1){
s=s+your_country$$prop[i+j-1]^2
}
your_table$$index[i]=1-s
c=c+1
s=0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr, try:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarise(index = 1 - sum(prop^2))
```